# Laravel partial mocked model not invoked

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mockery, partial-mocks

I'm using **laravel (4.2)** framework to develop a web application (PHP 5.4.25). I've create a repository-interface that was implemented with eloquent-repository, I use that repository inside a UserController:

```
#   app/controllers/UsersController.php

use Gas\Storage\User\UserRepositoryInterface as User;

class UsersController extends \BaseController {
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;

    }

    public function store() {
        $input = Input::all();
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $this->user->getRoles());

        if ( $validator->passes() ) {
            $this->user->getUser()->username = Input::get('username');
            $this->user->getUser()->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $this->user->getUser()->first_name = Input::get('first_name');
            $this->user->getUser()->last_name = Input::get('last_name');
            $this->user->getUser()->email = Input::get('email');
            $this->user->save();


            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My Repository implementation:

```
namespace Gas\Storage\User;

#   app/lib/Gas/Storage/User/EloquentUserRepository.php

use User;

class EloquentUserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface {

    public $_eloquentUser;

    public function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->_eloquentUser = $user;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        return User::all();
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return User::find($id);
    }

    public function create($input)
    {
        return User::create($input);
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->_eloquentUser->save();
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return User::$rules;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->_eloquentUser;
    }
}
```

I've also create a UsersControllerTest to testing the controller and all works fine, the user was added to the DB. After I mocked my **UserRepositoryInterface** because I don't need to test the DB insert, but I just want to test the controller

```
class UsersControllerTest extends TestCase {
    private $mock;

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function mock($class) {
        $mock = Mockery::mock($class);

        $this->app->instance($class, $mock);

        return $mock;
    }

    public function testStore() {
        $this->mock = $this->mock('Gas\Storage\User\UserRepositoryInterface[save]');

        $this->mock
            ->shouldReceive('save')
            ->once();

        $data['username'] = 'xxxxxx';
        $data['first_name'] = 'xxxx';
        $data['last_name'] = 'xxxx';
        $data['email'] = 'prova@gmail.com';
        $data['password'] = 'password';
        $data['password_confirmation'] = 'password';

        $response = $this->call('POST', 'users', $data);

        var_dump($response->getContent());
    }
}
```

My ruote file:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException : Method save() from Mockery_0_Gas_Storage_User_UserRepositoryInterface should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

---

Why the mocked method **save** has not be called?

What is wrong?

---

**EDIT:** without partial mock all works fine, now the question is: why with partial mock it doesn't work?

---

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the namespace of the class you're mocking is different in the "mock" method call from what you're got in your "use" statement on your controller. One starts with "Gas" and the other starts with "Way."

Comment: @patricksayshi it is my mistake that I made while I was writing the question

Comment: laravel is not suited for mocking in context of unit-testing. so why do you try? (not that this falls into wrong tool for the job category)

Comment: @hakre I don't understand what you said. But I followed a lot of guides that suggested me this kind of approach. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-laravel-controllers--net-31456

So, why do you say that laravel is not suitable for mocking??

Comment: I wrote that laravel is not suitable for unit-testing and mocking. That is because of what is known as (global) static state. For detailed questions about the tutorial on the tutsplus website, please contact the author and ask him/her for your more concrete issues. In case there is an understanding problem. It's totally valid to ask on Stackoverflow concrete programming questions, I don't want to wish away that in case you get the impression.

Comment: @hakre Common misconception. Facades are easily mockable by design even though they look like global static calls. EDIT: http://laravel.com/docs/testing#mocking-facades

Comment: @PapaSmurf can we see the route in routes.php that is pointed at `UserController@store`? It looks like your method isn't even being called - otherwise you'd get errors about how "getUser()" etc isn't defined.

Comment: @patricksayshi as I wrote, the test without mocked model works fine, and the new user is add to a DB. So the ruote.php works fine and my method is called.

Comment: @hakre how can you said that laravel is not suitable for mocking? I read a lot of guides that contains a lot of examples of mocking with laravel. Can you show me where is write that laravel is not suitable for mocking?

Comment: @PapaSmurf why is there `[save]` on the end of "'Gas\Storage\User\UserRepositoryInterface[save]'" -- could that be causing the problem?

Comment: @patricksayshi is for parti al mocking, when you don't want mock all methods of an object, in tris way I mock only 'save' method, and the other methods not.

Comment: Have you tried it without that `[save]` part? It seems like that would confuse the IoC container. I.e., it would return the correct mock if your controller constructor was type-hinted to expect  "Gas\Storage\User\UserRepositoryInterface[save]". But it's type-hinted to expect "Gas\Storage\User\UserRepositoryInterface", so the IoC container will return whatever you've previously bound to that interface. You want it to overwrite the original IoC binding, but since '[save]' is there, and it's a different string, I'd expect it will only create a new binding and not return the mock to the test.

Comment: @PapaSmurf: I wrote unit-testing *and* mocking. That was meant as together, both at the same time for the overall general design of laravel. You can not mock therein. You might be able to mock your models but only as long as they are exterior to laravel static access.

Comment: @hakre there is nothing in OP's code that can't be mocked. I unit test and mock objects in laravel all day every day. You are right that you can't mock static calls to models. But OP has none of those. Static calls to facades (Input::all(), Validator::make() etc...) can indeed be mocked, it's part of Laravel's design. 

I still believe the problem here is that the "[save]" string is confusing the IoC container. Removing it should fix this problem, at which point philipbrown's answer below is going to become very important.

Comment: @hakre you're right, without partial mock all works fine and my mocked call is invoked. But why with partial mock it doesn't work? I need partial mock of my repository.

Comment: @PapaSmurf I think you meant to reply to me. It doesn't work with the partial mock because, on the IoC container, you bind `UserRepositoryInterface[save]` to the mock you've created. But your *application code* never asks the IoC container to provide an instance of `UserRepositoryInterface[save]`. You can see in the controller constructor that it asks for `UserRepositoryInterface`. I'm not sure you can use a partial mock at all for this scenario. I'm curious - why use a partial mock at all? If it were me I'd just mock the whole class and fret no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking back at your code, it seems like you should be able to use partial mocks just by changing your mock function to something like this:

```
public function mock($class) {
    $mock = Mockery::mock($class);
    $ioc_binding = preg_replace('/\[.*\]/', '', $class);
    $this->app->instance($ioc_binding, $mock);

    return $mock;
}
```

Comment: I've implemented your mock function in my code, but when I run the test I received the following error: `BadMethodCallException : Method Mockery_0_Gas_Storage_User_UserRepositoryInterface::getRoles() does not exist on this mock object`. It seems that the partial mock doesn't work, but it expected that all methods of the object mocked are implemented.

Comment: Well, at least you know that now your mock is being passed to the test. "It seems that ... it expected that all methods of the object mocked are implemented" - that is exactly right. You need to use "shouldReceive()" to tell the mock what to do for *every method* that will be called on it. Yes, that is a serious pain in the ass. You'll write better / simpler code in the long run if you design your classes with that in mind. For example, your repo's `save()` function could accept *all* the input data and pass it to the model. Then your UserController doesn't need to know at all about the model

Comment: I would have liked separate business logic and dao (data access object), for these reason I put my Input validatio inside the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the mock to expect the `save()` method, but the `save()` is on the Eloquent model inside the Repository, not the Repository you are mocking.

Your code is currently leaking details of the implementation of the Repository.

Instead of calling:

```
$this->user->getUser()->username = Input::get('username');
```

You need to pass an instance of the `User` into the Repository:

```
$this->user->add(User::create(Input::all());
```

Or you pass the array of `Input` into the Repository and allow the Repository to create a new `User` instance internally:

```
$this->user->add(Input::all());
```

You would then mock the `add()` method in your test:

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('add')->once();
```

The comments about Laravel not being suited for mocking or unit testing are wrong.

Comment: I've tried to do what you said, instead call `save()`, i call `create(Input::all())` but the outcome is the same, my mocked call is ignored. I've add my Repository implementation to my question.

Comment: Without partial mock `$this->mock = $this->mock('Gas\Storage\User\UserRepositoryInterface');` works fine, but with `$this->mock = $this->mock('Gas\Storage\User\UserRepositoryInterface[save]');` it doesn't work. Why?